# when spring cloud config server calls the github repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config-server

I mean spring cloud config server fetches all client api's configuration during startup ?

or

spring cloud config server fetch the client API configuration, when that client api calls the config server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is controllable via a property:

`spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start`

> Flag to indicate that the repository should be cloned on startup (not on demand). Generally leads to slower startup but faster first query.
> Default:
> false

So the default behaviour is that the repo will only be cloned when a client first makes a request to the server, but if you set the property to true, then the server will clone the repository when it starts and the configuration will be available to the client's first request faster